# How to get latest NuGet artifact version with JFrog Artifactory REST API, based on property?

Tags: jenkins, nuget, artifactory, devops

Artifact management system is **JFrog Artifactory Pro X**.

According to [REST API of JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties) in my Jenkins job with REST API I try to get latest artifact version of a specific package, in this case the id is "MyLib".

My NuGet package is stored here: `https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/storage/projectx-nuget/MyLib/MyLib.1.0.0.nupkg?properties=nuget.version`, which results in following JSON response:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "nuget.version" : [ "1.0.0" ]
  },
  "uri" : "https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/storage/projectx-nuget/MyLib/MyLib.1.0.0.nupkg"
}
```

Also with following URL: `https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/storage/projectx-nuget/MyLib/MyLib.1.0.0.nupkg?properties=nuget.id` I get valid JSON response:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "nuget.id" : [ "MyLib" ]
  },
  "uri" : "https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/storage/projectx-nuget/MyLib/MyLib.1.0.0.nupkg"
}
```

I tried with following URL `https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/versions/_any/_any?nuget.id=MyLib`, but got

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
}
```

What is the correct URL to get the latest version, based on the property "nuget.id"?

Comment: why there are two _any ? typo ?

Comment: @error404 According to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties the usage is `GET /api/versions/{repo}/{path}?[listFiles=0/1]&[<property key>=<property value>]&[<property key>=<property value>]`, where ´{repo}: Specify a repository to search through or replace with "_any" to search through all repositories´ and ´{path}: Specify a path to search through or replace with "_any" to search through all paths´. So I replaced both variables with ´_any´.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc artifactory/api/versions : Search for artifacts with the latest value in the "version" property. Only artifacts with a "version" property expressly defined will be returned.

In your case you do not have the "version" property set (I guess) but only "nuget.version" which is extracted metadata from the nuget packages during indexation.

Just set a "version" property on the package and the REST call will work.

You can automate this by using a user plugin in artifactory that will set the "version" property after the package has been written.

Another solution without the need of a user plugin would be to use the native nuget api for example with nuget v3 api :

https://artifactory.myserver.net/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/projectx-nuget/query?q= MyLib&prerelease=false

Will give you a json response with latest version (and also a list of other versions as mentionned in doc https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource  : "The metadata contained in the search result object is taken from the latest package version. Each item in the versions array is a JSON object " )

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just checked: The Nuget package element has a property "version" under section "NuPkg Info", which is set. Under section "General" no "version" property is available. Not sure, which would be the right one?!

Comment: The one I'm referring to is under "Properties" tab. There you'll find all nuget metadata (available in the NuPkg Info tab" with "nuget." prefix (such as nuget.version, nuget.dependency, nuget.authors,...). Here if you add a "version" property the call will work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I could check by deploying a package with additional "version" property and got a valid JSON response with the URL in my question. For the ones who want to deploy with additional properties, just have a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221228/1001717. Note to have "Annotate" permission.